# How to display my data from my own database in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I don't know where to insert the select query. I import a external Database(Sqlite browser) in my project and i don't know how to display the data from my database to listview.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String DB_PATH = null;
    public static String DB_NAME = "extenalDBS";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query("wordbank", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your database helper class

```
Cursor getDatafromDB(){ return getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT 
* FROM TABLE_NAME",null);}
```

And to read it in java class

```
List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<>();
Bean bean;
Cursor cursor = databaseHelperInstance.getDatafromDB();
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
 {
 do{ 
    bean = new Bean();
    String a = cursor.getString(0);
    String b = cursor.getString(1);
    String c = cursor.getString(2);
    String b = cursor.getString(3);

    bean.setA(a);
    bean.setA(b);
    bean.setA(c);
    bean.setA(d);

    list.add(bean);

   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
 }
```

this will prepare a list for your custom adaptor of your listview.

Comment: Can you explain it to me, i mean the process of this code?  please ?

Comment: We make a method in DBhelper class of return type cursor which holds the table data. On receiving end we make a cursor and call that method. Now we check if the cursor has a starting point if yes then we'll follow the loop till cursor have next moves means next values or more precise table rows from DB. Those nos are just the column no.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , now im going to test it

Comment: I have a problem,  i can display the data using Toast but , in listview , still i dont get it

Comment: Bean is my Databasehelper?

Comment: BEAN class its a temporary holder of data and acts a passage between DB and arraylist like- `public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable{  
private int id;  
private String name;  
  
public Employee(){}  
  
public void setId(int id){this.id=id;}  
  
public int getId(){return id;}  
  
public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}  
  
public String getName(){return name;}  
  
}  `